# How to keep overflowing content in X direction with overflow-y: auto?

Tags: css, overflow, pseudo-element

`::after` pseudo element is used to render an arrow:

[image]

However, when `overflow-y: auto` is added to the container, the arrow is cut off:

[image]

Overflowing in the X direction should be fine (i.e. the arrow should be visible), but overflowing in the Y direction should result in a scrollbar.

Is it possible to keep both the scrollbar and the arrow?

```css
.flex {
  background-color: #eee;
  width: 100px;
  height: 160px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 2px solid #333;
}

.item {
  background-color: #ccc;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #777;
  padding-left: 4px;
  line-height: 28px;
  position: relative;
}

.item3::after {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 15px 0 15px 15px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #ccc;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item item3">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6433475/2518285)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS overflow-x: visible; and overflow-y: hidden; causing scrollbar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421966/css-overflow-x-visible-and-overflow-y-hidden-causing-scrollbar-issue)

Comment: Thanks @BrettDonald for the pointer. I see that `.flex` automatically gets `overflow-x: auto`, but it's not clear to me what the best solution to keep both the scrollbar and the arrow in 2023 :)

Comment: You might need a solution similar to this: https://css-tricks.com/popping-hidden-overflow/

Comment: Thanks again for the pointer, but this is almost a 10 years old solution, and it requires JS. I'm wondering whether these days there is a better CSS only solution.

Comment: There is no better solution because the spec says it must work this way. “The visible/clip values of overflow compute to auto/hidden (respectively) if one of overflow-x or overflow-y is neither visible nor clip.". https://www.w3.org/TR/css-overflow-3/#overflow-control

Comment: I guess I'm looking for some creative CSS-only solutions here (happy to add extra elements if needed).

Answer (score 3):

Not the most elegant solution but I allowed for some more width for the indicator arrow by adding a wrapper with a wider width around the whole thing. The border is added on top with a pseudo element. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421966/css-overflow-x-visible-and-overflow-y-hidden-causing-scrollbar-issue) for a more complete explanation of the overflow property.

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 115px;
  height: 160px;
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper::before {
  content: "";
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #eee;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}


.wrapper::after {
  content: "";
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.flex {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow-y: auto;
}



.item {
  background-color: #ccc;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #777;
  padding-left: 4px;
  line-height: 28px;
  position: relative;
  max-width: calc(100% - 15px);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.item3::after {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 15px 0 15px 15px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #ccc;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="flex">
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="item item3">Item</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that you want the scrollbar bar inside the container (as it appears in your image) and want the arrow outside of the container. **That's not possible. However, I have a few ideas that can be considered.**

As shown in [iicaptain's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76937378/21849374), the width of items can be calculated to compensate for the arrow so that it doesn't get clipped.

```
.item {
  width: calc(100% - 15px);
}
```

The snippet includes examples of when there is and isn't overflow, using your given code with structural modifications.

```css
*, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.flex {
  width: 115px;
  height: 160px;
  background-color: #eee;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.item {
  position: relative;
  width: calc(100% - 15px);
  padding-left: 4px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #777;
  line-height: 28px;
}

.item3::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 15px solid transparent;
  border-right-width: 0;
  border-left-color: #ccc;
}


.example {
  display: flex;
  column-gap: 5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="example">

  <div class="flex">
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="item item3">Item</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
  </div>

  <div class="flex">
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="item item3">Item</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

---

I played around with [iicaptain's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76937378/21849374) and can suggest modifications.

The `.wrapper::before` pseudo-element was used just to provide a background color. If the background color is wanted, it can be added to the `.wrapper` rule and there's no need for this pseudo-element.

```
.wrapper {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

The `.wrapper::after` pseudo-element is used to render the border around the container. The width can be declared so that the right-side border is in a preferable position, such as to the left of the arrow.

```
.wrapper {
  width: 115px;
}

.wrapper::after {
  width: 87px;
}
```

The snippet shows examples of this with and without overflow, as well as with and without a background color.

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 115px;
  background-color: #eee;
}

.wrapper::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 87px;
  height: 100%;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.flex {
  height: 160px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.item {
  position: relative;
  width: calc(100% - 15px);
  padding-left: 4px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #777;
  line-height: 28px;
}

.item3::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 15px solid transparent;
  border-right-width: 0;
  border-left-color: #ccc;
}


.example {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 3em;
  column-gap: 3em;
}

.example:nth-of-type(2) .wrapper {
  background-color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="example">

  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="flex">
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item item3">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="flex">
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item item3">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>


<div class="example">

  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="flex">
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item item3">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="flex">
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item item3">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

---

If you want to open a can of accessibility issues and/or have a case where users don't have to be able to scroll, the width and background-color of the `.wrapper::before` pseudo-element can be used to hide the scrollbar.

```
.wrapper::before {
  width: 115px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 115px;
}

.wrapper::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 115px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: white;
}

.wrapper::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 87px;
  height: 100%;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.flex {
  height: 160px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.item {
  position: relative;
  width: calc(100% - 15px);
  padding-left: 4px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #777;
  line-height: 28px;
}

.item3::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 15px solid transparent;
  border-right-width: 0;
  border-left-color: #ccc;
}


.example {
  display: flex;
  column-gap: 5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="example">

  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="flex">
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item item3">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="flex">
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item item3">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```